# select from database just can get first data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
    Dim reserveTime As String
    Dim Timer As String = ddlTime.SelectedValue
    Dim dat As String
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Beauty shop\Beauty shop\Beauty.accdb'")
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        conn.Close()
    End If
    conn.Open()
    Dim reserveDate As String = Calendar1.SelectedDate
    Dim bookingTime As String = "SELECT Booking_Date,Booking_Time FROM CustomerBooking where Booking_Date='" & reserveDate & "'"
    Dim sqlcommand2 As New OleDbCommand(bookingTime, conn)
    Dim dr2 As OleDbDataReader
    dr2 = sqlcommand2.ExecuteReader
    If dr2.HasRows Then
        dr2.Read()
        Dim count As Integer = dr2.FieldCount
        While dr2.Read()
            For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
                dat = dr2.Item("Booking_Date")
                reserveTime = dr2.Item("Booking_Time")
            Next
        End While
        dr2.Close()
        If Timer = reserveTime And dat = reserveDate Then
            ShowTimeLbl.Text = "This time have been reserve"
        Else
            Dim sqlString As String
            sqlString = "Insert INTO CustomerBooking(Customer_Name, Package_Name, Price, Booking_Date, Booking_Time, Card_Bank, Cardholder_Name, Card_Number,Expired_Month,Expired_Date) VALUES ('" & User_Name & "','" & Package_Name & "','" & Price_Package & "','" & Calendar_Book & "','" & Time_Book & "','" & Card_Name & "','" & Card_Holder & "','" & CreditCard_Number & "','" & Month_Card & "','" & Year_Card & "')"
            Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand(sqlString, conn)
            sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
            Response.Redirect("ConfirmBook.aspx?Name=" + Master.NameMaster + "&UserName=" + User_Name + "&PackageName=" + Package_Name + "&PackagePrice=" + Price_Package + "&Calender=" + Calendar_Book + "&TimeBook=" + Time_Book + "&CardName=" + Card_Name + "&CardHolder=" + Card_Holder + "&CreditCardNumber=" + CreditCard_Number + "&MonthCard=" + Month_Card + "&YearCard=" + Year_Card)
        End If
    End If
```

when i choose time all date cannot run， what is my problem， i want to compare the date and the time， if time has been booking it will show full，but just can read first date  ， why cannot run second date？the date is same

Comment: The sql code will be crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. This is practically begging to get hacked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have kept an extra dr.Read before while loop.

```
If dr2.HasRows Then
        ***dr2.Read()***
        Dim count As Integer = dr2.FieldCount
        While dr2.Read()
            For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
```

Remove the extra read() statement and get the field count inside while loop. It should work fine.

```
If dr2.HasRows Then           
     While dr2.Read()
         Dim count As Integer = dr2.FieldCount
         For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
```

UPDATE-
I am putting a pseudo code just to give you an idea. There is a lot of room for improvement. But since it is not a code review, I will keep quite on that matter.

```
    query = "SELECT Booking_Date,Booking_Time FROM CustomerBooking where Booking_Date= <inputDate> & and Booking_Time=<inputTime>"
    dr2 = get datareader using <query>
    If dr2.HasRows Then
    'It means there are records in DB with input date and Time so show error             

    Else
       'code to insert'

    End If
```

Comment: cannot work also， the problem now is when i choose 10 am on 25/3/2015，but 27，28，and so on  all 10 am also cannot booking

Comment: I can see few logical mistakes in your code. Anyway, what I understood of your problem is you need to check if input date and time is already booked. For this, you can change where clause in your select query to include time column also. So if this select query return any row i.e. if dr2.HasRows is truthy then given date and time is already booked. Else insert the row. It is not necessary to loop through all records of that date.

Comment: can write which part code is wrong？

Comment: Dim dr2 As OleDbDataReader
        dr2 = sqlcommand2.ExecuteReader

        If dr2.HasRows Then
            While dr2.Read()
                Dim count As Integer = dr2.FieldCount

                For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
                    dat = dr2.Item("Booking_Date")
                    reserveTime = dr2.Item("Booking_Time")


                Next
            End While
            dr2.Close()

Comment: my logic is when the time and the date have been book，then other time but at the same date can book

Comment: I have updated the answer. HTH.

Comment: finally can solve the problem， thank you very much =D